# Problem with fancyhead/rhead using Devanagari

Tags: xetex, fancyhdr, devanagari

There seems to be some problem with fancyhead/rhead when I use a Devanagari font.  My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{footnpag}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,left=1.1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\san}{
\catcode`\^=12
\catcode`\~=12
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Shobhika Bold}}

\begin{document}
\rhead{\san pa~nca}
{\san pa~nca}
\end{document}
```

The output is below. The pa~nca in the rhead is wrong and the body is right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to get to work was inputting the UTF-8 text without the mapping.  Changing the catcodes seems to be finicky.  But this worked for me in XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{footnpag}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[script=Devanagari]{sanskrit}

\newfontfamily\devanagarifont{Shobhika}[
  Script=Devanagari,
  Scale=MatchLowercase ]

\newfontface\translitfont{Shobhika Bold}[
  Script=Devanagari,
  Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit,
  Scale=MatchLowercase ]

\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,left=1.1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}

\newcommand{\san}{\catcode`\^=12\catcode`\~=12\translitfont}

\begin{document}
\fancyhead[R]{\textbf{\textsanskrit{पञ्च}}}
{\san pa~nca}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would prefer a most robust solution as the ~n appears in many of my documents and in many different scripts. If it were a few documents, your solution could be adopted.

Comment: @Sundar I’d be interested in one too. If there’s another input method you could use, that might be easier to work with?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this problem is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{footnpag}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{skt}
\usepackage[total={6.5in,8.75in},top=1.2in,left=1.1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\sj}{\char"091E}

\newcommand{\san}{
\catcode`\^=12
\catcode`\~=12
\fontspec[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis-sanskrit]{Shobhika Bold}}
\begin{document}
\rhead{\san pa{\sj}ca}
{\san pa~nca}
\end{document}
```

But I am seeking a more robust solution.